# is sync state with prop bad in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

If I do this, passing prop as default state, it won't update if I do

```
const MyComp = ({ isOpen: _isOpen }) => {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(_isOpen)

return <div>{isOpen.toString()}<button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}></button></div>
}
```

I fixed it with this

```
const MyComp = ({ isOpen: _isOpen }) => {
const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
setIsOpen(_isOpen)
}, [_isOpen])

return <div>{isOpen.toString()}<button onClick={() => setIsOpen(true)}></button></div>
}
```

is this an anti-pattern?

Comment: Naming a prop the same as a state seems like a real anti-pattern

Comment: @Mat what should I name it? can't think of better name, to me, they're the same thing.

Comment: Your prop is, according to you, a "default state". Name it something that tells the reader when they see it in the code that it is a default, not a changing state value.

Comment: What are you trying to do? To control whether it is open both from the component itself and from the parent? What should happen if they disagree?